# Unable to Invoking a Skill with a Specific Request from echosim.io

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Here is the Alexa Skill code:

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world Received an event");
    console.log("event=");
    console.dir(event);
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        console.log("LaunchRequest called()");
        this.response.speak('Hello World Init!').listen("I am listening SayHelloInit");
        this.emit(':responseReady');
        //this.emit('SayHelloInit');
    },
    'HelloWorldIntent': function () {
        console.log("hello world intent called");
        this.response.speak('Hello World How are you!').listen("I am listening sayhello");
        this.emit(':responseReady');
        //this.emit('SayHello');
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        const speechOutput = 'This is the Hello World Sample Skill. ';
        const reprompt = 'Say hello, to hear me speak.';

        this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('See you later!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'SessionEndedRequest': function () {
        console.log("SESSIONENDEDREQUEST");
        this.response.speak("SessionEndedRequest. Goodbye!");
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'Unhandled': function() {
        console.log("UNHANDLED");
        const message = 'Unhandled';
        this.response.speak(message).listen(message);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
};
```

Here are some observed strange behaviors:

From the Alexa simulator in the Amazon Developer Console, could not invoke the skill by "start hello world to go home", the response is "Sorry, I don't know that.". But after I  invoke the skill by "start hello world", I can invoke by "start hello world to go home" and get response "Hello World How are you!".

From Echosim.io, I can invoke the skill by "start hello world", but I could never invoke by "start hello world to go home". It responses with "Sorry I do not know that". Also, none of the reprompt speech is played out.

From cloudwatch log, sometimes I see "SessionEndedRequest" sent to the lambda function with the reason code "USER_INITIATED". I did not say any of "stop, cancel" etc. How is the USER_INITIATED SessionEndedRequest triggered? Is this somehow related to the fact that reprompt speech is never played out?

"go home" is mapped as the following:

```
            {
              "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
              "samples": [
                  "hello",
                  "say hello",
                  "who are you",
                  "go home",
                  "hello world"
              ],
              "slots": []
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many posts having trouble getting the reprompt going lately. I think the SDK might not build the response as intended in the first line.

```
this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

Try instead this line.

```
this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
```

This should be equivalent to yours.

Regarding the problem with echosim.io. Do you use a proper microphone to record your utterance? In my experience, echoism.io had a lot of trouble identifying what i was saying even though i was using my headset microphone.

Instead, i would recommend to either use an echo device if possible or the newly introduced Test Simulator BETA in the developer console.

Comment: I saw a comment somewhere saying echosim.io does not play reprompt.